# Equality of matrix relations $\mathbf{M}_{R^k}=(\mathbf{M}_{R})^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, relations

Suppose that $R$ is a relation represented by the square matrix $\mathbf{M}_R$. I want to prove that $$\mathbf{M}_{R^k}=(\mathbf{M}_{R})^k$$
But I'm not sure where to begin. I'd like a hint or two. I tried a proof by induction, but I'm not sure it's valid.

Proof: Consider $k=1$. Then $\mathbf{M}_{R^1}=\mathbf{M}_{R}=(\mathbf{M}_{R})^1$.
Assume $\mathbf{M}_{R^k}=(\mathbf{M}_{R})^k$, then we show that $\mathbf{M}_{R^{k+1}}=(\mathbf{M}_{R})^{k+1}$
\begin{align*}\mathbf{M}_{R^{k+1}} &= \mathbf{M}_{R^k}\mathbf{M}_{R} \\ &= (\mathbf{M}_{R})^k\mathbf{M}_{R} \\ &= (\mathbf{M}_{R})^{k+1}\end{align*}
Then for any integer $k\geq 1$, $\mathbf{M}_{R^k}=(\mathbf{M}_{R})^k$